# User defined function type not defined while creating connection to database

Tags: sql, database, excel, sql-server-2012, vba

While opening database connection I get an error

> User defined type not defined

I am able to create connection in same macro, but I have to create function for connection to use any were in project.

```
 Option Explicit
    Public CN As ADODB.Connection
    Public Function Connection() As ADODB.Connection

      If CN Is Nothing Then
        Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
        Dim Con_str As String

        Con_str = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & getvalue("User_id") & _
                ";Password=" & getvalue("Password") & _
                ";Initial Catalog=" & getvalue("Database_Name") & _
                ";Data Source=" & getvalue("Server_Name") & ";"

        Debug.Print Con_str

      CN.Open Con_str
      End
      Set Connection = CN
    End Function
    Sub teting()

    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open connetion(), adOpenStatic 'CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ActiveSheet.range("A10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End Sub
```

What is the actual cause of this issue?

Thanks,

Uttam Patel

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library, where x.x is replaced by the version number that you have available.

You'll find it under tools --> references in the VBA editor.